# Spring batch skip Limit Exceeded but no release the resource

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am using partition to read multiple csv files in spring batch.

I have put the skip-limit=2 and csv contains more then 2 the records who have exception. Also added the 
                    
                
So code will skip the record if  FlatFileParseException exception occured till skip-limit <=2. Now record number 3 alos throwing FlatFileParseException then skip-limit exceeded and throws the SkiplimitException that is fine.

But i am doing some operation like if skip-limit exceeded then trying to moving same file to another folder but it is not happening and throwing IOException. I have tried and done some R&D on it and found that csv file resource is still open.

So how i can handle this kind of scenario? please help me as much as possible... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurred because - probably - resources are all freed during close phase of a step (when it terminate, with easy words) and before they are "locked".
If you want to delete/move your csv you have to do that in a second step where you move/copy failed resources; in previous step just set flags to remember you which resources should be cleared.

An easy test (but I'm not confident it will be a successful try) you can call your `FlatFileItemReader.close()` but I'm worried that can interfere with normal SB resources lifecycle.

Comment: Hi Luca, Thanks for giving your view but we can solve by this way. Instead of opening file take the all byte to byte[] abd read all bytes from byte[] array so we are not physically open the file.